# Java StringTokenizer.nextToken() skips over empty fields

Tags: java, string, tokenize

I am using a tab (/t) as delimiter and I know there are some empty fields in my data e.g.:

```
one->two->->three
```

Where -> equals the tab. As you can see an empty field is still correctly surrounded by tabs.
Data is collected using a loop :

```
 while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(strLine, "\t");
    String test = st.nextToken();
    ...
    }
```

Yet Java ignores this "empty string" and skips the field.

Is there a way to circumvent this behaviour and force java to read in empty fields anyway?

Comment: Use `string.split("\t")` instead.

Comment: from the java docs of String tokenizer "StringTokenizer is a legacy class that is retained for compatibility reasons although its use is discouraged in new code. It is recommended that anyone seeking this functionality use the split method of String or the java.util.regex package instead."

Comment: Just a heads up that it looks like using `string.split("\t")` won't return any trailing empty tokens at the end. If that matters, use `string.split("\t", -1)`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Thank you at all. Due to the first comment I was able to find a solution:
Yes you are right, thank you for your reference:

```
 Scanner s = new Scanner(new File("data.txt"));
 while (s.hasNextLine()) {
      String line = s.nextLine();
      String[] items= line.split("\t", -1);
      System.out.println(items[5]);
      //System.out.println(Arrays.toString(cols));
 }
```

Answer (score 16):

There is a [RFE in the Sun's bug database](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4418160) about this `StringTokenizer` issue with a status `Will not fix`.

The evaluation of this RFE states, I quote:

> With the addition of the `java.util.regex` package in `1.4.0`, we have
> basically obsoleted the need for `StringTokenizer`.  We won't remove the
> class for compatibility reasons.  But `regex` gives you simply what you need.

And then suggests using [`String#split(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) method.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `Apache` Commons [StringUtils.splitPreserveAllTokens()](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#splitPreserveAllTokens%28java.lang.String%29). It does exactly what you need.

Answer (score 1):

I would use [Guava's Splitter](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Splitter.html), which doesn't need all the big regex machinery, and is more well-behaved than String's `split()` method:

```
Iterable<String> parts = Splitter.on('\t').split(string);
```

Comment: call me paranoid but I really don't think introducing a new dependency for something so simple (not to mention included in the standard library) is a bit of an overkill. I still appreciate the info regarding Guava splitter not needing regex tho :)

Comment: I agree, generally, but Guava is so useful and provides so many additional useful classes that it's part of my "default" dependencies for nearly all my projects (unless it's a very small self-contained library).

Comment: Guava is awesome, for sure. I still havent fully explored the awesomeness that is Guava, thus it's always nice to learn new stuff about it.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the Java Doc http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html you can use the Constructor `public StringTokenizer(String str, String delim, boolean returnDelims)` with `returnDelims` `true`

So it returns each Delimiter as a seperate string!

**Edit:**

***DON'T*** use this way, as @npe already typed out, StringTokenizer shouldn't be used any more! See JavaDoc:

> StringTokenizer is a legacy class that **is retained for compatibility
>   reasons** although its use **is discouraged in new code**. It is recommended
>   that anyone seeking this functionality use the **`split`** method of `String`
>   or the `java.util.regex` package instead.

Comment: I am still faced with the problem that I have multiple tabs behind eachother (indicating blanc fields) that the blank value is NOT put into the array..how can I fix this?

Comment: returnDelims returns the delimiter. This does not reply the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class TestStringTokenStrict {

/**
 * Strict implementation of StringTokenizer
 * 
 * @param str
 * @param delim
 * @param strict
 *            true = include NULL Token
 * @return
 */
static StringTokenizer getStringTokenizerStrict(String str, String delim, boolean strict) {
    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(str, delim, strict);
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

    while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
        String s = st.nextToken();
        if (s.equals(delim)) {
            sb.append(" ").append(delim);
        } else {
            sb.append(s).append(delim);
            if (st.hasMoreTokens())
                st.nextToken();
        }
    }
    return (new StringTokenizer(sb.toString(), delim));
}

static void altStringTokenizer(StringTokenizer st) {
    while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
        String type = st.nextToken();
        String one = st.nextToken();
        String two = st.nextToken();
        String three = st.nextToken();
        String four = st.nextToken();
        String five = st.nextToken();

        System.out.println(
                "[" + type + "] [" + one + "] [" + two + "] [" + three + "] [" + four + "] [" + five + "]");
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = "Record|One||Three||Five";
    altStringTokenizer(getStringTokenizerStrict(input, "|", true));
}}
```