# How to count white spaces in a given argument?

Tags: java, string, token, tokenize

I find it strange why spaceCount doesn't add up when the expression is "12 + 1". I get an output 0 for spaceCount even though it should be 2. Any insight would be appreciated!

```
public int countSpaces(String expr) {
    String tok = expr;

    int spaceCount = 0;

    String delimiters = "+-*/#! ";
    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(expr, delimiters, true);

    while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
        if ((tok = st.nextToken()).equals(" ")) {
            spaceCount++;
        }
    }
    return spaceCount; // the expression is: 12 + 1, so this should return 2, but it returns 0;
}
```

Comment: @clcto: the third parameters indicate that the delimiters should be returned as token as well

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java StringTokenizer.nextToken() skips over empty fiels](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11409320/java-stringtokenizer-nexttoken-skips-over-empty-fiels)

Comment: Your code worked fine for me. It returned 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code seems to be ok, but if you want to count spaces you can use this :

```
int count = str.length() - str.replace(" ", "").length();
```

Comment: Simple and effective code. Just don't forget to check null conditions here.

Comment: I'd just make sure I understood the time complexity of `replace` before using this approach with "large" strings with "lots of" spaces. It could be very inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

A tokenizer is overkill (and doesn't really help you) for this problem. Just loop through all the characters and count the spaces:

```
public int countSpaces( String expr )
{
    int count = 0;
    for( int i = 0; i < expr.length(); ++i )
    {
        if( expr.charAt(i) == ' ' )
            ++count;
    }
    return count;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another one line solution could be the following which also performs a NULL check to the string.

```
int spacesCount = str == null ? 0 : str.length() - str.replace(" ", "").length();
```

Answer (score 0):

Can also use:

```
String[] strArr = st.split(" ");

if (strArr.length > 1){
   int countSpaces = strArr.length - 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will find white spaces, including special ones.
You can keep the pattern so you don't need to compile it every time. If just need to search for " ", a loop should do it instead.

`Matcher spaces = Pattern.compile("\\s").matcher(argumentString);
    int count = 0;
    while (spaces.find()) {
         count++;
    }`