# validate null string while using tokenizer

Tags: java, stringtokenizer

I have a String like this: `String sample = "a|b||d|e";` 
and I'm trying to split the string with tokenizer

```
StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(sample, "|");
String a = tokenizer.nextToken();
String b = tokenizer.nextToken();
String c = tokenizer.nextToken();
String d = tokenizer.nextToken();
```

When I use the above code, the String variable `c` is assigned to the value `d`.
 
`StringTokenizer` doesn't initialize a `null` value to `String c`.

How can we validate and assign default value like `-` if it is `null`?

Comment: A quote from the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html): _"StringTokenizer is a legacy class that is retained for compatibility reasons although its use is discouraged in new code. It is recommended that anyone seeking this functionality use the split method of String or the java.util.regex package instead."_

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java StringTokenizer.nextToken() skips over empty fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11409320/java-stringtokenizer-nexttoken-skips-over-empty-fields)

Comment: As @1615903 said it is not possible with `StringTokenizer`.
But you can do the same using `String` using `split` method.

Answer (score 2):

As others have said, you can use `String#split()` on pipe, which would return an entry for the empty match.  In the code snippet below, I use streams to map the empty entry into dash per your desired output.

```
String sample = "a|b||d|e";
String[] parts = sample.split("\\|");
List<String> list = Arrays.asList(parts).stream()
    .map(o -> {
        if (o.equals("")) {
            return "-";
        } else {
            return o;
        }
    }).collect(Collectors.toList());

for (String part : list) {
   System.out.println(part);
}
```

**Output:**

```
a
b
-
d
e
```

**Demo here:**

## Rextester